# QPdfWriter creates empty PDF file (0 bytes)

Tags: c++, pdf, qt5

Here's my code that creates an empty pdf file:

```
    QPdfWriter pdf("test.pdf");
    pdf.setTitle("test image");
    pdf.setCreator("My App");
    pdf.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize::A4));
    pdf.setPageOrientation(QPageLayout::Landscape);
    pdf.setResolution(600);
    // pdf.setPageMargins(QMargins(30, 30, 30, 30));
    pdf.newPage();
    QPainter pnt;
    pnt.begin(&pdf);
    pnt.drawImage(0, 0, img); // image is 5905x4724
    pnt.drawText(100, 100, "Hello World"); // just as an alternative
    pnt.end();

    img.save("test.tiff", nullptr, -1);
```

The image file is valid and can be opened. But even if it wasn't - the text is also not drawn...

Comment: http://sscce.org/ - please provide a reproducible example we can cut'n'paste, compile and run and get the same results

Comment: The code works fine for me and produces the file as expected.

Comment: What does your `main` look like? Do you not have a `QApplication` instance?

Answer (score 0):

So silly. I overwrote the PDF file with the images file. It could not find the image file format "pdf" and wrote a 0 byte file. I'm so sorry.